# No se muestran los datos en un Report Viewer, pero sí se muestra el diseño (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

Estoy haciendo un programa, el cual después de unos procesos me muestra un comprobante por medio de un Report Viewer. Originalmente, estuve trabajando el uso del componente por medio visual, en el que el *data source* se llena por medio de una selección y no por código, pero he notado que el componente reconoce el reporte que hice con anterioridad pero no reconoce el *data source* que utilicé. Cabe recalcar que hago lo lleno por medio de un *Data Set*.

[image: Muestra de que el data source no se reconoce]

Intenté de hacer el envío de datos manualmente, programado, pero no se cargan los datos y sale el reporte con los campos vacíos, solo se logra apreciar el reporte visual.

[image: Reporte sin datos]

[image: Código]

Comment: Hola, viéndolo así por arriba el problema podría ser el código que declaras en el using, ya que el objeto de dejara de existir cuando se salga del using, prueba creando de la manera clásica

Comment: IDataBase de = new ()...

Answer (score 0):

En el form donde tienes tu Report Viewer deberías revisar en el Form.designer.cs que la información del Data Set sea la correcta así también como el Binding Source que necesitas para que le puedas pasar correctamente los datos a tu reporte a través de un Data Set

[image: Form.designer.cs]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La informacion del binding source debe ser las misma que se tiene generada en el Form.designer.cs

El Form.designer.cs se genera automáticamente cuando se van agregando elementos al Form, así que debes asegurarte que todo este declarado correctamente.